# How to insert if IG is the result of a cross join - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using Apex 18.2

- User chooses a software application from a shuttle.
- Clicks a button called "Refresh Tools List"
- The result is displayed in the first IG.
- User clicks in the row of the IG which populates a page item called "Tool ID"
- User then clicks a button called "Refresh App Insert" which populates a second IG called "App Insert".
- App Insert IG consists of user applications that do not have the selected Tool ID already.
- A cross join is executed and the result is the user applications with the selected Tool ID.
- I am not able to insert. Can someone point me in the right direction?

The APEX$ROW_STATUS does not seem to have a value. When I click the IG "Save" button it does not save nor do I receive an error message.

Comment: "I am not able to insert" is difficult to debug. What happens? Any error? If so, which one? Did you run the page in debug mode and - once you face the problem - review debug info?

Comment: Nothing. No error. Nothing in debug.

Comment: Maybe check to see if all your button properties (and any associated dynamic actions) are set correctly; and also try your browser's web tools by hitting F12.